# Python: How to print a regex matched string?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to match a part of the string (a particular word) and print it. Exactly what `grep -o` does.
My word is "yellow dog" for example and it can be found in a string that spans over multiple lines.

```
[34343] | ****. "Example": <one>, yellow dog
        tstring0 123
        tstring1 456
        tstring2 789
```

Let's try this regex `mydog = re.compile(', .*\n')` 
and then 
`if mydog.search(string):` print only the matched words.

How do I get only "yellow dog" in the output?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using a capture group and findall:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """[34343] | ****. "Example": <one>, yellow dog
...         tstring0 123
...         tstring1 456
...         tstring2 789"""
>>> mydog = re.compile(', (.*)\n')
>>> mydog.findall(s)
['yellow dog']
```

If you only want the first match then:

```
>>> mydog.findall(s)[0]
'yellow dog'
```

Note: you'd want to handle the `IndexError` for when `s` doesn't contain a match.

Answer (score 11):

If you don’t specify a capture group, the text that is matched by the whole expression will be contained withing `matchResult.group(0)`. In your case, this would be `', yellow dog\n'`. If you just want the `yellow dow`, you should add a capture group to the expression: `, (.*?)\n`. Note that I also changed the `.*` into a `.*?` so that it will be non-greedy and stop when it finds the first line break.

```
>>> s = '''[34343] | ****. "Example": <one>, yellow dog
        tstring0 123
        tstring1 456
        tstring2 789'''
>>> mydog = re.compile(', (.*?)\n')
>>> matchResult = mydog.search(s)
>>> if matchResult:
        print(matchResult.group(1))

yellow dog
```